# What is the synonym of the word stray?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any synonym to the word "stray"? I need that to better understand the phrase "Stray observations". Word for word translation doesn't say much to me

Comment: As an adjective, it can mean itinerant, random, distracting...  More context would be helpful to those who would be helpful.

Comment: Where did the phrase "stray observations" come from...a translation site?  If so, from what language?  As Rob_Ster said, some context would be helpful, such as the source of the phrase.

Comment: Sorry, here is the source.http://blog.statuspage.io/customer-service-email I actually googled this phrase and it seemed to be sort of idiomatic...

Comment: In that case, it means simply "other observations".

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Stray*** means *separated from the main body; occurring away from the regular course or habitat; isolated.*(OED)

So, in a scientific context,  a ***stray observation*** is a *statistical '**outlier**'*  - an observation whose value lies outside the set of values considered likely according to some hypothesis (usually one based on other observations); an isolated point.(OED)